# How to prevent re-assignment of a class method outside the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

I want some of my class methods to be not re-assignable outside (or both outside and inside) of the class. `A`'s functions are objects too in python, is it possible to accomplish what I want? Here is the method;

```
def x(self):
    """Return x, the horizontal distance between the shape and the leftmost
    of the screen, in pixels.
    """
    return self.__x
```

Now outside of the class, it is easy to mess with this method;

```
shape = Shape(10, 20)
shape.x = 30
print(shape.x)  # Prints 30
print(shape.x())  # TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Is it possible to prevent this kind of assignment of class methods?

Comment: It's not possible to prevent it, but you can make it harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `__setattr__` method to check to see if the key is in a forbidden list for example...

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.__x = a
        self.__y = b

    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in ('x', 'y'):
            raise TypeError(f"You can't change {key}")
        super(Shape, self).__setattr__(key, value)


shape = Shape(11, 20)
shape.z = 100  # OK
print(shape.z)
print(shape.x())
shape.x = 30  # raise an exception
```

**note**: As @Chepner noted, Overriding `__setattr__` just prevents you from changing the value of `x` via an assignment statement, not from changing it at all. like `object.__setattr__(shape, 'x', 30)`

Comment: `object.__setattr__(shape, 'x', 30)`.

Comment: Overriding `__setattr__` just prevents you from changing the value of `x` via an assignment statement, not from changing it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Make `x` a property with no setter, not a method.

```
class Shape:
    ...

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
```

Attempts to assign to `x` will result in an exception:

```
>>> shape.x = 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

If you really want something that must be called, have the property return that instead of the value the function will return.

```
class Shape:

    @property
    def x(self):
        return lambda: self.__x
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job in this context, but is there a way to achieve what I want, non-override-able methods?

Comment: You are going to have to define some sort of descriptor whose `__set__` method prevents the assignment, like `property.__set__` does. `function.__set__` isn't defined at all, so attempts to create an instance attribute that shadows the class attribute succeed.